# O(1) - access method of an object that is key in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

```
from random import randint
class Node():
    def GetUse(self):
        return self.Used
    def setUse(self):
        self.Used=True
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = int(id)
        self.Used=False
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
    def __str__(self):
        return f"(id: {self.id}, Used: {self.Used})"
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"(id: {self.id}, Used: {self.Used})"
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id > other.id

N=10
dDict={Node(i):[randint(100,200),randint(100,200)] for i in range(1,N+1)}
dDict[Node(1)].setUse() # ERROR
```

In O(1) - BigO notation -, how access a method of an object that is key in a dict?

In O(n) we can do its:

```
for i in dDict:
    if i==Node(1): i.setUse()
```

Comment: Either create another mapping using primitives as keys or implement `Node.__hash__`.

Comment: You may want to look into using a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for `Node` instead of writing all of that standard boilerplate manually.

Comment: Why are you storing this information in the key instead of the value?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq They already have Node.__hash__

Comment: The design here is flawed.  When you're finished, you don't have any list of Node objects  unless you enumerate the keys.  Perhaps you wanted `dDict = [(Node(i),randint(100,200),randint(100,200) for i in range(1,N+1)]`.  Now, you can do `dDict[0][0].setUse()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up a key that does the action when an equal key is found:

```py
class SetUse(Node):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.id == other.id:
            other.setUse()
            return True
        return False

print('before:', dDict)
SetUse(1) in dDict
print('after: ', dDict)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVOxTsMwEB3Y_BWnLo1FQAkTihQmBFsWYEIoCvWZWEqTYDsDqrLwGyxd4KP4GuzESUNJJYZ6ifPu-fnO9-7jq37TeVVut5-N5meX3yfvXFZrkFnJzEes60rq7k-UmqyKTClIKoYejQiYxZDDLeoHhZ7CgjvULom6kSVY9NyE2UhXs_SRF9_LBkdymopS6DTt6D4Itn9EMIjB5OaZ0IzYTVaoqVqeqdyp_c3VBj2nSieH8HVMoNI5ygNV2lTinmH2k_NKy4N38oXJPIKNU2h9sHkPgN23dDHRklgfT6zQ_y3salcXSeIwIOxarHS86bwgaPToLOKFQeBfBAH194En4JUEYXpl7fSCXugnpyFtiXPVXW8LKzjx1vE7Jvhct3Zxu3rUGZX-CrmLR5NOsN5rpJa27OUzmnoxWvrQPRUlrsCQ2ifosIGacY0ygpHaj6KbyGEyfwA)):

```
before: {(id: 1, Used: False): [198, 110], (id: 2, Used: False): [157, 133], (id: 3, Used: False): [134, 111], (id: 4, Used: False): [102, 121], (id: 5, Used: False): [147, 184], (id: 6, Used: False): [114, 100], (id: 7, Used: False): [125, 161], (id: 8, Used: False): [133, 186], (id: 9, Used: False): [161, 104], (id: 10, Used: False): [160, 119]}
after:  {(id: 1, Used: True): [198, 110], (id: 2, Used: False): [157, 133], (id: 3, Used: False): [134, 111], (id: 4, Used: False): [102, 121], (id: 5, Used: False): [147, 184], (id: 6, Used: False): [114, 100], (id: 7, Used: False): [125, 161], (id: 8, Used: False): [133, 186], (id: 9, Used: False): [161, 104], (id: 10, Used: False): [160, 119]}
```

Comment: Downvoter: Please let us know what the issue is.

Comment: This is technically possible, but mutative `==` comparisons are the kind of thing to only use as a last resort. In this situation, it'd be a much better idea to redesign the program's data structures, such as with the auxiliary dict the other answer suggests, or by putting the "used" flag in the value instead of in the `Node`, or by including the `Node` instance in the value.

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe such a redesign would be better, maybe not. But that's not what the question asks. And this saves memory compared to having an auxiliary dict like juanpa suggested. (I've done this before for that reason, to "intern" dict keys without extra memory, for a problem where there wasn't enough memory for an extra dict).

Comment: @user2357112 Btw, note I deliberately wrote a separate class and didn't touch the original one. While the original is a piece of *data*, mine is really rather *code/algorithm*, not data. It's just a callback object for the dict to call for candidates, and I really just replaced the OP's loop-search with the dict's more efficient search by hash. And an algorithm being mutative is normal. I also could make the comparisons *not* mutative and instead store the found key somewhere (that's what I did in that other case), and then use that key afterwards. But I find it cleaner the way I did it here.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks. Your solution is optimal enough, it is a tradeoff between save memory and search in loop-For - O(n).

Comment: @user14272 Hmm, what do you mean with tradeoff? It's both O(1) memory and O(1) time. Usually we speak about tradeoffs between aspects when we *can't* be optimal regarding all of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Dictionaries map *keys to values*. The only constant time behavior is *retrieving a value from a given key*. You'll have to make another mapping. Perhaps, after

```
a_dict = {Node(i):[randint(100,200),randint(100,200)] for i in range(1,N+1)}
```

You can do:

```
node_index {node.id: node for node in a_dict}
```

Then you can access your nodes:

```
node_index[1].setUse()
```

using the ID in constant time.

Comment: Not true. Can be done.